# C# - Change child when parent changes

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I am doing an app in C#, Windows Forms.

In this app I have a main form that has several Elements in it. This "Element" class is inherited by others ("ElementLabel","ElementPicture","ElementGraph").

At some point i might want to change in "batch" mode some property of several elements, whichever they are. For example, I might want to change the property "Value" of all the selected elements.

The problem is, for example, when the property "Value" is changed in the parent class, I also want to change the property "Text" of a "Label" that exists in the child class "ElementLabel". I've seen a lot of topics on changing the parent through the child, but not otherwise.

Am I missing something here or do I just have a bad design and a situation like this isn't even supposed to happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing inheritance with a parent-child relationship. Parent-child implies *composition* not *inheritance*. Please clarify what you mean so we can help you better.

Comment: It sounds a bit like an [`Ambient Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties.aspx), which is dependent on its parent - like `Control.BackColor`. Is that the sort of thing you're thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its hard to say what the best option is without knowing more about your architecture, but subclasses can intercept events in the parent class by overriding methods.  For example, in your ElementLabel class:

```
public override void set(String key, object newValue) {
    if (key.Equals("Value"))
        set("Text", "New label text!");
    base.set(key, newValue);
}
```

If you want a more general solution, you could include an observer pattern in your parent class; see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Well, this is kinda the obvious answer. I knew I was missing something really simple, but couldn't see it at the time. Of course that overriding the parent method in the child class and then calling it from the child did the job for me (I was doing it before for other methods, shame on me). Thank you! PS -  I'll check that observer patter anyway, it seems interesting :) PS2 - I would upvote your answer, but can't do it due to lack of reputation :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use for the data a class (or classes) that implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Then you would have to pass to the child controls references to a "master" property that you used to control the state. (It would be ideally used by a Controller class.) (I'll refer to this object as the "master property object".)

Each of the child controls would subscribe to the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event.

Then when the Controller changes the value of one of the master property object's properties, it will raise the `PropertyChanged` event, and each interested child can respond appropriately.

This approach helps to decouple the controller from the views.

The sequence is:

1. Before creating the child controls, create the master property object. Keep a reference to this in the Controller or Main Form (if you're using that as a controller).
2. Pass to each child control that needs it, a reference to the master property object.
3. Each child control should subscribe to the master property object's `PropertyChanged` event.
4. Write an appropriate handler for each child. It will have access to a reference to the master property object, so it will be able to see the new values of any properties.
5. When a property needs to be changed, the Controller simply sets the property as desired. The property setter implementation should raise the `PropertyChanged` event, and that will notify all the interested child controls, who will update their UI in response.

[EDIT] This is in fact an implementation of the Observer pattern that Reyan mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the simple solution from @Reyan did the job for me :) I would upvote your answer, but can't do it due to lack of reputation :/